# Countif using Indirect

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use Countif using indirect function.

here is the [trix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pO-vilA2FcgkJ0QeN3jwa0rnLfMbF7NkfYZOSOW4rBs/edit?usp=sharing)

I've cells which has direct referring like Alphabet & Major. I'm trying to get count which are not Alphabet & Major and get the value in "other"

[image]

I'm using

```
=if(B$1="","",COUNTIF(INDIRECT(B$1&"!$A:$A"),$A4))
```

to get the value of others. Not sure I'm doing right.  Any inputs on this.

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: It seems your output is correct. What is problem you are facing with this?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: If you look at tab #1 there are values "Incorrect" & "Not right" and the count of these is 2 and The value 2 should appear in sheet 1 cell B4

Comment: Updated question with desired output screenshot.

Comment: check the last line OR the phrasing of " I'm trying to get count which are not Alphabet & Major and get the value in "other""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula utilizing [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) instead and pull to the right

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(B$1&"!$A:$A"),"<>"&$A2, 
          INDIRECT(B$1&"!$A:$A"),"<>"&$A3,
          INDIRECT(B$1&"!$A:$A"),"<>")
```

[image]